# Ember.js - Remove Only One instance of Object with removeObject

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

### Explanation

I have a very simple calorie tracking app that uses the Nutritionix API to search for food items based on the user's input. The results are added to a `results` array, which is then displayed to the user. When a user clicks the "Add" button next to one of these items, the calories are added to a counter, and the food itself is added to a `todaysFood` array (using Ember's `pushObject`). This is then used to display which food the user has consumed today in a separate table.

When a user clicks the `remove` button next to one of the `todaysFood` items, it triggers an action, `removeItem`, and passes the index of the item clicked to `removeItem`. This index is used inside of Ember's `removeObject` to remove the item from the `todaysFood` array, and thus update the view (remove that item from the list and its calories from the counter).

### Problem

When more than one of the same item are added to `todaysFood`, clicking `remove` on just one of those items removes ALL of the instances from `todaysFood`, and the view. This makes sense to me now, because of the docs' example:

```
var cities = ['Chicago', 'Berlin', 'Lima', 'Chicago'];
cities.removeObject('Chicago');  // ['Berlin', 'Lima']
cities.removeObject('Lima');     // ['Berlin']
cities.removeObject('Tokyo')     // ['Berlin']
```

However, it also only removes the calories of ONE item, not all instances.

So, the question is: How do I remove only ONE instance of that item when `remove` is clicked? I.e., if two tacos are added, and I click `remove` on one, I only want that ONE to be removed (from the list and the calories).

Here is my `removeItem` action:

```
removeItem(index) {
        var self = this;

        // Store property paths for easy access
        let todaysPath = this.get('healthData').todaysFood;
        let caloriesPath = 'healthData.calories';

        this.set(caloriesPath, this.get(caloriesPath) - Math.round(todaysPath[index].fields.nf_calories));

        todaysPath.removeObject(todaysPath[index]);

    }
```

#### Disclaimer

I'm aware that I may not be handling this correctly at all. I'm open to any suggestions to make this better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have index of object to remove so you can try using [`removeAt()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_removeAt) method:

```
todaysPath.removeAt(index);
```

Comment: So simple! Exactly what I needed and works like a charm. Thank you!